# Author-year citation in LaTeX

Tags: bibtex, natbib

How can I do this style of citation in LaTeX `(Shannon 1948)`

what package I need?

I have used

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

and the output was `[1]` and I need to to be for example `(Shannon 1948)`

Comment: your code snippet shows that you are using `bibtex` and not `biblatex`. Create a _complete_  example that we can see what you really did.

Comment: The bibliography style should be `plainnat`. `plain` is not compatible with the `natbib` authoryear option.

Comment: A very powerful [examples listing for natbib](http://merkel.texture.rocks/Latex/natbib.php)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I solve it

it should be

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

and use `\citep` instead of `\cite`

Comment: For future readers, \citep will produce (Author et al., 2006) and \cite will produce Author et al. (2006).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following overleaf template "**elsarticle-template-harv.tex**" & "**elsarticle-harv.bst**". So, when you create the in-text citation (Author year) use either of the following codes.

```
\citept{<label>} ==> Jones et al. (2015)
\citep{<label>} ==> (Jones et al., 2015)
```

Download the overleaf template from this [link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/elsevier-article-elsarticle-template/vdzfjgjbckgz)