# Latex - bibliography style - error

Tags: natbib, texstudio

I am using the following packages for bibliography in an article.

```
\usepackage{amsmath,natbib,wrapfig}
```

Since the references from my bib file jaarefer was appearing as ? in the pdf file i used the following command.

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}
```

My bib style is the following
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{jaarefer}

When I compile the tex file with the following content.

```
"and the dynamical evolution, most of the OCs in general survive only up to a few 100 Myr \citep{PortegiesZwart2010}"
```

The output in the pdf is the following.

```
"and the dynamical evolution, most of the OCs in general survive only up to a few 100 Myr[1]. "
```

I want the the cited reference to occur as the following

```
"and the dynamical evolution, most of the OCs in general survive only up to a few 100 Myr (PortegiesZwartetal.2010)."
```

How do I achieve this? The MWE is given below

```
\documentclass{jaa}  

%%download jaa.cls and save it in the folder of  your source file  


%%suggested packages to be included  
\usepackage{graphicx}  

%%The following packages are included with the class file.  
%%Please download if these packages are not included  
%%in your local TeX distribution   
%%txfonts,balance,textcase,float,amsmath  

\usepackage[round]{natbib}  
\usepackage{amsmath,wrapfig}  
\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}  

\newcommand{\aap}{A\&A}  

\begin{document}\sloppy  

***%% \sloppy was in the    sample tex file. I haven't changed that***  
%%include \doinum{number}for the DOI number in the header  
%%include \volnum{number} for the volume number in the header  
%%include \year{yyyy} for  year of publication in the header  
%%include \pgrange{num--num} page range of article in the header  
%%include \artcitid{num} for the article citation id  
%%include \lp to print last page of the article  
%%include \setcounter{page}{pagenum} for the exact starting page of the article  

\doinum{12.3456/s78910-011-012-3}  
\artcitid{\#\#\#\#}  
\volnum{000}  
\year{0000}  
\pgrange{1--}  
\setcounter{page}{1}  
\lp{1}  


\section{Introduction}  
the dynamical evolution, most of the OCs in general survive only up to a few 100 Myr \citep{PortegiesZwart2010}. 


\end{document}
```

I downloaded the tex and  class file form the following website.

http://www.ias.ac.in/Journals/Journal_of_Astrophysics_and_Astronomy/Information_for_Authors

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You will need to use a `natbib`-compatible style that allows for author-year citations. For lack of an MWE I can't test the ideas offered in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144764/35864. See also http://www.jmlr.org/format/natbib.pdf

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I have added a MWE.

Comment: @moewe thanks for the link but it didn't work. Could you please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class and example file one can download from http://www.ias.ac.in/Journals/Journal_of_Astrophysics_and_Astronomy/Information_for_Authors do not use dedicated bibliography package.

The citations are produced entirely manually in `jaaSample.tex`

```
Section text here (Clark \& Caswell 1976; Zwicky 1957).
```

The bibliography is produced as follows

```
\begin{theunbibliography}{} 
\vspace{-1.5em}

\bibitem{latexcompanion} 
Clark D. H., Caswell J. L. 1976, MNRAS, 174, 267 
\bibitem{latexcompanion} 
Dickey, J. M., Salpeter, E. E., Terzian, Y. 1978, Astrophys. J. Suppl. Ser., 36, 77
\bibitem{latexcompanion} 
Radhakrishnan, G. C. {\em et al.} 1980, in Evans A., Bode M. F., eds, Non-Solar Gamma Rays (COSPAR), Pergamon Press, Oxford, p. 163
\bibitem{latexcompanion}
Starrfield S., Iliadis C., Hix W. R. 2008, in Bode M. F., Evans A., eds, Classical Novae, 2nd edition, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, p. 77
\bibitem{latexcompanion}
Van Loon J. Th. 2008, in Evans A. et al., eds, R S Ophiuchi (2006) and the Recurrent Nova Phenomenon, ASP Conference Series, Volume 401, p. 90
\bibitem{latexcompanion} 
Zwicky, F. 1957, Morphological Astronomy, Springer-Verlag, Berlin, p. 258
\end{theunbibliography}
```

Note the ridiculous and frankly incorrect use of `latexcompanion` as a key for all references. But since they don't cite using `\cite` that does not really matter.

I have never seen the environment `theunbibliography`, but if its use is required it seems unlikely to me that you could use a standard `.bst` style without modifications.

Now it becomes even more ... interesting. The class not only defines `theunbibliography` it also defines `thebibliography`. Additionally it forces `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`. `unsrt` does not really strike me as a style that works well together with the required author-year citation style.

If you want to submit to this journal my advice would be to create the bibliography and citations manually. That will probably the least hassle, I'm not sure if they can deal with `.bbl` files or other bibliography packages.

Comment: I use \cite throughout my document. Is there a way that this can be fixed in the tex file or should I just type in the cited references?

Comment: @Bryan Well, the document class does not look good. So I'm not sure if they can handle `\cite` and BibTeX.

Comment: So I'll just go ahead and modify my \cite to just the manes and then type out the references towards the end.

Comment: Also I have a problem using the scientific notation \degree and \arcsec. I tried loading the siunitx package but this gives me an error in the document.

Comment: @Bryan The thing with `siunitx` could be a new question. But don't get your hopes up too high. As I say, the class and example document don't make me think that they can support all kinds of TeX packages.